# interest rate swap schedules

Tags: interest-rate-swap

Is there a source describing how the schedules(start, end, dcf, payment) involved in a basic IRS are computed?

Depending on when the dates are adjusted, the schedules can be different.

Thanks

Comment: Dimitri Vulis has some answers that might help you: https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/36636/dimitri-vulis?tab=answers